# If there are entire $G_k$s such that $f=\exp\circ\exp\circ\cdots \circ\exp\circ G_k$ ($k$ times), must $f$ be constant?

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, exponential-function

I am a French guest and I hope that my English isn't too bad...

So here is my issue:
I consider an entire function $f$ which satisfies the following property for each complex number $z\in \mathbb{C}$:

$\forall ~ k \in \mathbb{N}^*$, there exists an entire function $G_k$ that satisfies
$$f(z)=\exp_k(G_k(z))$$
where $\exp_k$ denotes $\exp \circ \exp \circ ...\circ \exp$, $k$-times.

In other words, I can take (as many times as I wish) the $\log$ of my function $f$, and it will always give an entire function that doesn't vanish on $\mathbb{C}$.

Is $f$ a constant? (surely different from $0$...)

Thanks everyone!

(PS: This forum is so cool!)

Comment: English is great!

Comment: The remark "surely different of $0,1,\dots $" is misleading, and contributed to some wrong now-deleted answers. It's true that $f$ cannot be $0$, but the other constants are not excluded. For example, $f\equiv 1$ can be written as $\exp(2\pi i)$ and also as $\exp_2(\log(2\pi i))$ for an arbitrary choice of $\log$, and so on...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I must say that at first I was quite skeptical  that such function could exist, but it turned out that one can prove its existence.  I have written down the proof but I will give here only sketch it (you should not have any problems computing it for yourself, nice exercise)

Let us define $b_1=2\pi \rm i m_1$ and $\displaystyle b_n=2\pi \rm i m_n+ \log b_{n-1}$ and 
$$f_n(z)=\exp_{n}\left[b_n+ \frac{z}{b_1b_2\ldots b_{n-1}}\right],$$
where $\exp_{n}[z]=\exp\circ\cdots\circ\exp(z)$ $n$-times. One must find a sequence of  integers $m_k>0$ such that  the sequence  $f_n(z)$ will converge on every compact set. With some more effort one can prove that limit function $g(z)=1+z+ \mathcal{O}(z^2)$ have the desired property.

Comment: I dont get it ?

Comment: Try to do it as an exercise! Take $\{D_n\}$ compact exhaustion of $\mathbb{C}$ and show that $m_n$ can be taken so large that $|f_n-f_{n+1}|<1/n$ on D_n. By taking k times logarithm of $f_n$ and $f_{n+1}$ that they can be again $1/n$ apart on $D_n$ (increas $m_n$ if necessary) and see what happens.

Answer (score -1):

I think that the concept of *'order of an entire function'* can help you to get an answer.
(See definition in W. Rudin : Exercise 2, Ch. 15 of ; or alternatively here : [Wiki - Entire function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function) )

Namely, your entire function $f$ is clearly of infinite order (well, at least for k>1), while constant functions -like polynomials- are entire functions of order zero ...

NB: of course I'm not considering the trivial case where the $G_k$ are constant (and non-zero), in which case $f$ would be constant as well ...

Comment: Yes, but the question here is: does such a (non-constant) function exist? Your answer definitely doesn't address the problem...

Comment: The question was : is f constant ?

Comment: Daniel, not sure to understand your comment ... The initial question was : "is f constant ?"   <br/>The elements given in my post imply : "No f cannot be constant"  exception made of the trivial case mentioned in NB ...   <br/>The main argument I provided is based on the order of an entire function.

Comment: Since there is a complex solution $z_0$ to $e^z=z$, then obviously the function $f(z)=z_0$ satisfies the condition, and is constant with $G_k(z)=z_0$. So there is certainly at least a constant function with the property of the question. The question then becomes: is there a **non-constant** function $f$ satisfying the condition, or are all such functions constant?

Comment: @ Daniel Robert-Nicoud, sorry to insist but I don't get your logics here: the example you're providing in your last comment is just the 'trivial case' I was mentioning at the end of my answer, which I deemed not too informative for the problem at hand. (comment continued below)

Comment: In the general case the mismatch between the order implied by the two conditions (‘form of $f$’ and ‘$f$ constant’) precludes the existence of such $f$. And as far as I’m aware, the question was “is f constant?”: so the answer seems to me within the focus of the question (while your comment "Your answer definitely doesn't address the problem..." was not really appropriate). (cont. below)

Comment: Now if we assume that you are entitled to rephrase (modify) the question “the question becomes …” (I’m new to this website, I’m not quite familiar with all its rules) then the answer to your question becomes: “Yes, there are non-constant solutions to the Pb”, basically, the entire functions of strictly positive order (possibly infinite).   (more below)

Comment: More specifically, we can split the reasoning along two cases:   Case 1 ($k>1$), infinite order, regardless of the $G_k$.   Case 2 ($k=1$) will depend on the form of the functions $G_k$ , e.g. we will get a finite order if the $G_k$  are polynomials …   Hope this will help to clarify things out.

Comment: Ok, first of all, sorry if my first comment seemed harsh, I wasn't my intention. Secondly, I think you have misread the question. The OP asks: if a function $f$ satisfies the condition **for all $k$ at the same time**, must then $f$ be constant?

Comment: @Daniel Robert-Nicoud you're right on this one -thanks for drawing the attention to it. In this case, assuming this time that the condition is met **for all $k$**, indicates that we'll have to consider the intersection of solution sets among the ones discussed earlier, which is likely to be shrinking things out into the _empty set_ ... as for different $k$ we get completely different (and exclusive) sets of solutions. And this means that the answer to the question is eventually 'easier' than what I'd have thought! Now, Stabilo, any thoughts about the elements provided/developed so far?